# Change panelClass from SnackBar in Snackbar Component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use Material SnackBar to display messages and have an extra component for the SnackBar. In that component I want to change the `panelClass` value dynamically depending on the data/message and don't want to pass every time in the `openFromComponent` method the `panelClass` parameter.

Is there any way to do that? I couldn't find anything in the documentation. In the following code you can see my SnackBar Component TS.

```
export class SnackbarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public snackBarRef: MatSnackBarRef<SnackbarComponent>,
              @Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public data: any,
              @Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DEFAULT_OPTIONS) public options: any) { }
}
```

I am using my SnackBar Component with:

```
this._snackBar.openFromComponent(FewoSysSnackbarComponent, {
          data: {type: 'success/warn/info/error', text: 'MESSAGE'}
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and implemented a service which uses the SnackBar Component, here my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {MatSnackBar} from '@angular/material';
import {SnackbarComponent} from '../module/shared/snackbar/snackbar.component';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SnackBarService {

  constructor(public snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}

  show(message: string, type?: string, duration?: any) {
    this.snackBar.openFromComponent(SnackbarComponent, {
      data: {type: type ? type : 'info', text: message},
      panelClass: type ? type : 'info',
      duration: duration ? duration : 0,
      horizontalPosition: 'right'
    });
  }
}
```

With `duration = 0` the snackbar won't disappear.